# DegradedArray event on /dev/md0 without actually having a RAID

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raid, mdadm

Since I upgraded from Ubuntu LTS 10 to LTS 12, I have been getting error messages like:

```
 N  60 mdadm monitoring   Mon Sep  3 06:38  31/1022  DegradedArray event on /dev/md2:Ubuntu-1004-lucid-64-minimal
 N  61 mdadm monitoring   Mon Sep  3 06:38  31/1022  DegradedArray event on /dev/md0:Ubuntu-1004-lucid-64-minimal
 N  62 mdadm monitoring   Mon Sep  3 06:38  31/1022  DegradedArray event on /dev/md1:Ubuntu-1004-lucid-64-minimal
```

We do not have a RAID setup, and only have a single hard drive. Ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure you don't use a raid, then just remove the package :

```
sudo apt-get purge mdadm -y && sudo apt-get autoremove -y
```

reboot.